# password minimal length doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want my password to be at least 6 characters long and if it is less than 6 characters long it has to say an error but it does not say anything.

```
<?php
if (strlen($_POST['userPassword']) < 6 ) {
    $error[]=  "wachtwoord moet minimaal 6 karakters bevatten <br />";
} else {
    $cryptpass = md5($password);
    $query = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO users (userName,userPassword,userMail) VALUES (:userName,:userPassword, :userMail)");
    $query->bindParam(":userName", $_POST['userName']);
    $query->bindvalue(":userPassword", $cryptpass);
    $query->bindParam(":userMail", $_POST['userMail']);
    $query->execute();

    echo "gebruiker aangemaakt";
}

foreach ($error as $errors) {
    echo $errors;
}
?>
```

this is my form:

```
<form action="registratie.php" method="post">

        Username <br />
        <input type="text" id="user_input" name="userName" placeholder="userame" /><br />
        Password<br />
        <input type="password" id="pass_input" name="userPassword" placeholder="password" /><br />
        Password<br />
        <input type="password" id="v_pass_input" name="userPassAgain" placeholder="password" /><br />
        Email<br />
        <input type="email" id="email" name="userMail" placeholder="email"><br />
        <input type="submit" id="register" name="register"  value="Register" disabled="disabled" />

</form>
```

Comment: what output `var_dump(strlen($_POST['userPassword'])) `

Comment: You're not doing any error checking at all on your query, do that and turn on error reporting and you might find out why it isn't working.

Comment: If “does not say anything” you have a Fatal error: your db connection works? You have tested it? Check also `->prepare` result

Comment: @fusion3k, everything works fine. the only thing that isn't working is my $error.

Comment: It is working perfectly at my end.

Comment: If everything works fine, you see a text, because your code print a text in **any circumstance**

Comment: Depending on your php version you might need to add `$error = array();` before your `$error[]= ` line

Comment: Can you paste your form too?

Comment: @Epodax anyway, without array declaration, there is a notice, but the code works.

Comment: @fusion3k Ever as that might be, obviously something isn't working if nothing is getting echo'ed, I'm simply trying to limit the possible cause of errors, but without error reporting turned on this is looking more and more like a simple case of "I didn't do my debugging"

Comment: @alizia i have posted my form

Comment: @epodax my other $errors are working but this one is echo'ed before i fill in the form.

Comment: @Furkanyavuz You **need to follow** first Epodax advice: check for php errors (not your custom error system). See at apache error log for that. It is mandatory.

Comment: _"... long it has to say an error but it does not say anything."_ Does the error echo or does it not?! Please try and clarify the ACTUAL issue. If the error is echoed before the form is submitted it's a simple matter of doing `if(isset($_POST['userPassword'])){ <YOUR CODE HERE> }`

Comment: plus, is the form and PHP/PDO in the same file? how is this accessed, on a hosted site? local? if local, `http://localhost/file.xxx` or `file:///file.xxx`?

Comment: @Furkanyavuz, your code is absolutely working fine at me end :D

Comment: @fred-ii- it is local. it is accessed like : file:///file.xxx

Comment: there is the problem ^ @Furkanyavuz and why is this `disabled="disabled" />` for submit disabled?

Comment: @alizia well that is strange

Comment: @Furkanyavuz, try to echo something in your first condition. See if the control comes there or not.

Comment: @fred-ii- it is disabled because the user has to fill in everything.

Comment: @alizia the echo works. the problem is that before i can fill anything the $error is already echo'ed.

Comment: You can fix that by using `if (isset($_POST['userPassword']) && strlen($_POST['userPassword']) < 6 )` @Furkanyavuz

Comment: Also `if (!empty($error)){` before `foreach`

Comment: As an aside, you should prefer [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) or similarly secure methods for [password hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); unsalted md5 is terrible.

Comment: @alizia thanks is works

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire.

[Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html) .

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from comments:

> *"plus, is the form and PHP/PDO in the same file? how is this accessed, on a hosted site? local? if local, http://localhost/file.xxx or file:///file.xxx??*

and

> *"@fred-ii- it is local. it is accessed like : file:///file.xxx – Furkan yavuz"*

and

> *"there is the problem ^ @Furkanyavuz and why is this disabled="disabled" /> for submit disabled?"*

There's the problem. You have to run this off a webserver and not as `file:///file.xxx` directly in your web browser.

The browser itself won't parse PHP directives.

But as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or `http://example.com/file.xxx`.

If you don't have a webserver/PHP installed, you will have to install one or run it off a hosted website.

Sidenote: If you're running this off the same file, you will first need to check if the inputs are empty or not.

- Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Also, since you're using PDO, why are you using MD5 to store passwords with? It is no longer safe to do so now.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

**Important sidenote about column length:**

If and when you do decide to use `password_hash()` or crypt, it is important to note that if your present password column's length is anything lower than 60, it will need to be changed to that (or higher). The manual suggests a length of 255.

You will need to ALTER your column's length and start over with a new hash in order for it to take effect. Otherwise, MySQL will fail silently.

---

**Footnotes:**

Comments from Ali Zia:

You can fix that by using `if (isset($_POST['userPassword']) && strlen($_POST['userPassword']) < 6 )` @Furkanyavuz – Ali Zia 2 mins ago

Also `if (!empty($error)){` before foreach – Ali Zia 1 min ago

Sidenote: Using `!empty()` over `isset()` is better as it checks if it's both set and empty.

`if (!empty($_POST['userPassword']) && strlen($_POST['userPassword']) < 6 )`

---

**Regarding PDO/query/connection.**

The connection is unknown, whether it is in fact PDO.

Note that different MySQL APIs do not intermix. So, if you're using `mysqli_` or `mysql_` to connect with, that won't work with your PDO query.

Comment: thanks for the advise. i use md5 because it is a schoolproject and encyrption is not a must. my problem is fixed now thanks!

Comment: @AliZia Ah... thank "you" for the comments. I was in the process of typing that up, but you had posted your comments, and quoting you. *Cheers* :-)

Comment: @AliZia Always a pleasure Ali. We "all" learn from each other ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- True that. I always used `isset`. Now, i'll use `!empty` :D

Comment: @Furkanyavuz I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Comment: @AliZia `isset()` does have its use. Mostly for radio buttons/checkboxes. Using `isset()` for inputs could give false positives. `isset()` can be used for sessions, but it's best to use both `isset()` and `!empty()` for session arrays. There's no harm to use both for inputs, but it's just more work really.

Comment: @JayBlanchard you are right. i am slowly learning encyrption but at this time i have more important things to do.

Comment: No you don't @Furkanyavuz. The security and safety of your code and for those who use your code is your *number one priority*.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Please add me on skype. `syed_ali_zia`